# Getting name of running display server in python

Tags: python, linux, unix, xorg

How could I get name in Python of the display server that is used in current Linux session?
I want to know if user uses Xorg or Wayland for example.

Comment: you need to clarify what you mean by current session. The X-Protocol as used by the various X-Server implementations is a network-protocol. The X-Server(s) running on the machine executing an application might be different than the X-Server displaying the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need an Xlib `Display` pointer and a way to call [ServerVendor()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/servervendor) and possibly `VendorRelease()`.

<strike>With `pygtk`, you can use [gdk_x11_display_get_xdisplay()](http://developer.gnome.org/gdk/stable/gdk-X-Window-System-Interaction.html#gdk-x11-display-get-xdisplay) to get a `Display *`</strike>.

*Update:* I stand corrected: `gtkmm` has a binding to this function but `pygtk` apparently does not.

The library still might provide access to the information returned by `ServerVendor()` (a quick search shows several calls but most of them seem to be used for compatibility workarounds).

Even [Python-Xlib](http://python-xlib.sourceforge.net/) does not seem to provide a binding to `ServerVendor()`. You may have to write your own module.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know precisely what this does with Wayland, but you may be able to use `xdpyinfo` like so:

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen(['xdpyinfo'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
for line in p.communicate()[0].split('\n'):
    if line.startswith('vendor'):
        k, v = line.split(':')
        v = v.strip()
        print "%s=%s" % (k, v)
```